# How to make my Jasmine Http post test more efficient?

Tags: angular, jasmine, automated-tests, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am testing an angular 4 app using Jasmine/Karma. As of now I am testing my services. I have tested my first service successfully, that service just requests and returns a url. My next service is a post service. This service adds a model and a url to the page. I believe I have successfully mocked the service, but my code is not too efficient. I am trying to pass my data into 'body' so that I can pass bodyinto my expect statements. But I receive a few errors. Here is the spec:

```
      describe('httpService', () => {
        let service: HttpService;
        let httpClient: HttpTestingController;

        beforeEach(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
                providers: [HttpService]
            });

            service = TestBed.get(HttpService);
            httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController)
        });

        afterEach(() => {
          httpClient.verify();
        });

    it('should pass a model',  () => {

     const dummyPost: Test[] = [
    {userId: '1', id: 1, title: 'test', body: 'test'},
  ];

  service.add(dummyPost,'http://localhost:4200/dashboard').subscribe(body=> {
    expect(dummyPost.length).toBe(1);
    expect(dummyPost).toEqual(dummyPost);
  });

httpClient.expectOne({
  url: 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard'
}).flush({
  dummyPost
})
```

As you can see, I pass dummyPost to the expect syntax. I would rather pass body. I believe my syntax may be a little off. If I pass model, I get two errors :

```
Expected undefined to be 1.

Expected Object({ dummyPost: [ Object({ userId: '1', id: 1, title: 'test', body: 'test' }) ] }) to equal [ Object({ userId: '1', id: 1, title: 'test', body: 'test' }) ]
```

This has be also believe that maybe my test is not working as I think it is. If I pass the model, dummyPost, everything passes. I can even add more instances of the model and test for more then 1, and it passes. If it helps, here is the service I am testing:

```
   add(model, url: string): Observable<any[]> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':
        'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
    let options = { headers: headers };
    let body = JSON.stringify(model);
    return this.http.post(url, body, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you note yourself in the question, you should test the body, not `dummyPost`.

But the assertions can't work:

```
 expect(body.length).toBe(1);
 expect(body).toEqual(dummyPost);
```

The first one is redundant: the second one tests that the body is equal to dummyPost, and dummyPost is an array of 1 element. So if the second one passes, the first one will always pass.

But the body you send back is not an array:

```
.flush({
  dummyPost
})
```

So you're sending back an object, containign a single property named `dummyPost`, which is the dummyPost array. This is equivalent to

```
.flush({
  dummyPost: dummyPost
})
```

which is equivalent to

```
.flush({
  dummyPost: [
    { userId: '1', id: 1, title: 'test', body: 'test' }
  ]
})
```

Either the backend indeed returns such an object, and the expectations should be fixed, or the backend returns what you sent, unmodified, and the code should be

```
.flush(dummyPost)
```

Comment: So in my service, I pass two parameters, the url, and the model. To my understanding, the jasmine test is just a mock and the service is not actually looking for a model or url? So do the parameters matter in the line:      service.add(dummypost,"url"?  Or does it not matter what you pass, as long it matches the correct amount of  arguments. Thank you!

Comment: The URL matters, since you use `expectOne({
  url: 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard'
})`. If you passed a different URL, that method call would fail the test. The request body can be anything, since you don't make and expectation about it.  But expectOne() returns a TestRequest, so you could test that te service sends the correct value by getting the body out of the TestRequest.

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know what the syntax is in side of expectOne{()} to check the parameter I am trying to add? Checking the angular documentation, I found this: abstract match(match: string | RequestMatch | ((req: HttpRequest<any>) => boolean)): TestRequest[] I played around with it but cannot seem to implement it properly. Thank you.

Comment: `const testRequest = httpClient.expectOne({
  url: '...', method: 'POST'
}); expect(testRequest.request.body).toEqual(...); testRequest.flush(...);`

Comment: ah thank you very much. I am getting an error saying there are no open requests, found 1. I am guessing it is my syntax. Thank you once again.

Comment: When I move it outside the subscribe I get the object error too. hmmmm.

Comment: I can't help, because I can't see the code you're talking about. if you want help, ask another question, with the code, what you expect it to do and what it does instead.

Comment: Thank you, I added the new question.